# How to make AndroidTest in android studio when it has deleted?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have deleted AndroidTest in my project, but now I need that to test my project, how to create that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a new java file in {root project dir}/app/src/androidTest/java/com/company/name

Android Studio will recognize it as AndroidTest.

```
package com.company.name;

import android.app.Application;
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;

/**
 * <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html">Testing Fundamentals</a>
 */
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If your **androidTest** **package** has been deleted/not being shown, then do the following:

The best and easy way is to **open your Android project** in File Explorer (*My Computer/Windows explorer in Windows OS* )

Then go to **app-->src**

*(There you will already find your main folder)*

Now, **create a new package/folder in app-->src** and name it as **androidTest**

**NOTE: the name is case sensitive. Type as shown above.**

Now in you **app-->src-->main** folder, copy the java folder and paste it in **app-->src-->androidTest** folder.

Now in androidTest folder, open all the folder inside till the end and delete the existing java files.

Now in your Android Studio, you can clearly see the folder/package of androidTest made. Just **add new Java file** and write all the test code stuff there and its done.