# How to configure androidTest package in project?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I am working with an Android project where the androidTest package has been deleted from src and there is no package suffixed with '(androidTest)' in the project structure.

I am trying to create an androidTest package as I need to run instrumentation tests.

I have already tried the following:

1. Adding

   sourceSets {
       androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')
   }

to the Android block in my project level build.gradle.

2. Actually creating a folder named 'androidTest' in my file explorer and syncing with what I added in 1.

Both approaches fail, unfortunately. I am not sure how else I can configure Android Studio to know what folder I want to write and run instrumentation tests from. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I guess this answer will solve your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174895/how-to-make-androidtest-in-android-studio-when-it-has-deleted

Comment: Thx! Worked for me.